# immunity to Malaria

Tags: immunology, pathology

What is "immunity to the disease" in the following sentence?

> In some regions, the parasites are resistant to certain antimalarial drugs, particularly chloroquine.
>   People continually infected gradually develop **immunity to Malaria.**

Comment: where does that come from? can you give a reference? Is the text "People continually infected develop immunity to Malaria" directly from a source? Is there supposed to be some punctuation somewhere?

Comment: When there is one existing subclinical infection, it prevents another new superinfection. This is called premunity and is rather very important for malaria inendemic areas. Just thought of mentioning. Its different from the immunity you're talking of though.

Comment: I would think it is not immunity to the Plasmodium, but rather something like a system-free infection. They don't get the symptoms of Malaria any more, but they are still infected.

Comment: They might build up slowly an immune response to the manifestation of symptoms of malaria that arise when the microorganism is present in the blood, from what I remember. But can't get rid of it since it hides when not in the blood (cycles in the liver if I remember correctly.